# Implode values retrieved from database PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I stored values as `S5001:31,32,33|S5002:42,44,46|S5003:21,23,25`... etc.

in database, how to retrieve the values using `implode` function so that I can display the marks separately to find total for each registered number in HTML table?

```
$internalmark_col="mark_internal";
        $student_internal_marks_array = array();
        if(isset($student_internal_mark->$internalmark_col))
        {
            $internalmarks_stud_code_arr=explode(',',$student_internal_mark->$internalmark_col);
            foreach($internalmarks_stud_code_arr as $marks_each)
            {
                $internalcode_mark=explode(':',$marks_each);
                if(isset($internalcode_mark[0]) && isset($internalcode_mark[1]))
                    $student_internal_marks_array[$internalcode_mark[0]]=$internalcode_mark[1];
            }

        }

        print_r($student_internal_marks_array);
        exit;
```

For above code I got wrong output. Desired output is:

```
Register No | Mark 1 | Mark 2 |Mark 3 | Total 
-------------------------------------

S5001       | 3 | 2 | 3 | 8

S5002       |4 | 4 |6 | 14

S5003       |1 |3 |5 | 9
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Is your data stored using `serialize` ?

Comment: what output do you getting as now.

Answer (score 2):

From below code you will get desired output:

```
$data = "S5001:31,32,33|S5002:42,44,46|S5003:21,23,25";
    $d = explode("|",$data);
    foreach ($d as $value) {
        $register_no_arr = explode(":",$value);
        $register_no = $register_no_arr[0];
        $marks = explode(',',$register_no_arr[1]);
        echo '<br>Register No :- '.$register_no;
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($marks);$i++){
            echo "<br>Mark ".($i+1)." :- ".$marks[$i];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_split to read the row params:

```
$str = 'S5001:31,32,33|S5002:42,44,46|S5003:21,23,25';


$table = '<table>
<tr>
<th>Register No</th>
<th>Mark 1</th>
<th>Mark 2</th>
<th>Mark 3</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>';

$internalmarks_stud_code_arr=explode('|', $str);
foreach($internalmarks_stud_code_arr as $marks_each)
{   
    list($num, $m1, $m2, $m3) = preg_split('/(:|,)/',$marks_each);
    $table .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$num.'</td>
            <td>'.$m1.'</td>
            <td>'.$m2.'</td>
            <td>'.$m3.'</td>
            <td>'.($m1 + $m2 + $m3).'</td>
        </tr>';

}
$table .='</table>';         
print $table;
```

preg_split is a [core function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) that allows you to explode strings using a regex. In this case I already know that the sum of the elements separated by : and , is fixed (4 items), so I can use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) core function as well that saves the result of the split in four defined variables ($num, $m1, $m2, $m3)

```
list($num, $m1, $m2, $m3) = preg_split('/(:|,)/',$marks_each);
```

The regex I used /(:|,)/ is made up by / which are php regex delimiters and a group syntax between round brackets (). The pipe into group syntax means "or" so this (:|,) means "find : OR , ". Since my replacement pattern is quite easy and there's no need to use groups it can also be written as a range like this: /[,:]/ and It's even a better choice

Comment: I think it will be better if you can give a small explanation about the regex you used, may be helpful for new regex user to understand regex clearly.

Comment: You're right! I added more information about my snippet, hope It's more clear now

Answer (score 1):

```
$tot =0;
$internalmark_col = S5001:31,32,33|S5002:42,44,46|S5003:21,23,25;
$m = explode('|',$internalmark_col);
echo '<tr>';
foreach($m as $mark){
    $scode = explode(':',$mark);
    echo '<td>'.$scode[0].'</td>';
    $code = $scode[1];
    $smark = explode(',',$code);
    foreach($smark as $student_mark){
        echo '<td>'.$student_mark.'</td>';
        $tot += $student_mark;
    }
    echo '<td>'.$tot.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = 'S5001:31,32,33';
$str = str_replace(":", ",", $array);

list($register, $mark1, $mark2, $mark3) = explode(',', $str);

echo "<br>Register:" . $register . "<br>Mark1:" . $mark1 . "<br>Mark2:" . $mark2 . "<br>Mark3:" . $mark3;
```